# How to convert nullspace basis to a geometric interpretation?

Tags: linear-algebra

For the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}6&2\\3&1\end{bmatrix}$, I am asked to describe the nullspace. I found that the span of the basis is {$\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{3}\\1\end{bmatrix}$}, and I understand this is a line because it has dimensionality of 2, but the book says the line is $3x+y=0$. What is the process used to "convert" a basis to an equation? I felt like the answer would be $\frac{-1}{3}x+y=0$, but clearly not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a vector $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}$ is in the span of $\begin{bmatrix}-1/3\\1 \end{bmatrix}$, then $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}=\lambda \begin{bmatrix}-1/3\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ for some scalar $\lambda$. Hence
$$x=-\frac{\lambda}{3}\text{ and } y=\lambda \Longrightarrow x=-\frac{y}{3} \Longrightarrow x+\frac{y}{3}=0\Longrightarrow 3x+y=0.$$